# Airflow task not running on schedule with PrestoDB Query

Tags: pyspark, airflow, presto, airflow-scheduler

I have defined a Airflow sample task where I wanted to run a PrestoDB Query followed by a Spark job to perform a simple word count example. Here is the DAG I defined:

```
from pandas import DataFrame
import logging
from datetime import timedelta

from operator import add

import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

from airflow.hooks.presto_hook import PrestoHook

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(1),
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    }

dag = DAG(
    'presto_dag',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='A simple tutorial DAG with PrestoDB and Spark',
    # Continue to run DAG once per hour
    schedule_interval='@daily',
)

def talk_to_presto():
    ph = PrestoHook(host='presto.myhost.com', port=9988)

    # Query PrestoDB
    query = "show catalogs"

    # Fetch Data
    data = ph.get_records(query)
    logging.info(data)
    return data

def submit_to_spark():
    # conf = SparkConf().setAppName("PySpark App").setMaster("http://sparkhost.com:18080/")
    # sc = SparkContext(conf)
    # data = sc.parallelize(list("Hello World"))
    # counts = data.map(lambda x: (x, 1)).reduceByKey(add).sortBy(lambda x: x[1], ascending=False).collect()
    # for (word, count) in counts:
    #     print("{}: {}".format(word, count))
    # sc.stop()
    return "Hello"

presto_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='talk_to_presto',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=talk_to_presto,
    dag=dag,
)

spark_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='submit_to_spark',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=submit_to_spark,
    dag=dag,
)

presto_task >> spark_task
```

When I submit the task, about 20 DAG instances stay in the running state:
[image: Airflow DAG]

But it never completes and no logs are generated, at least for the PrestoDB Query. I am able to run the same PrestoDB Query from the Airflow's `Data Profiling > Ad-Hoc Query` section correctly.

I have intentionally commented out the PySpark code as it wasn't running and not of focus in the question.

I have two questions:

1. Why aren't the tasks completed and stays in the running state?
2. What am I doing wrong with the `PrestoHook` as the query isn't running?

Comment: **[1]** are you sure that your quer(ies) aren't reaching `Presto`? (check `Presto`'s web UI); because 20 `DagRun`s means at least 20 queries being fired on `Presto` *nearly* simultaneously so that can significantly slow down execution (while testing `Ad-Hoc Query` you only run single query) **[2]** have you configured [`remote-logging`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/config_templates/default_airflow.cfg#L49), because `..remote logs for running tasks are unavailable..` as told in [docs](https://incubator-airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html#logs)

Comment: Actually upon a second thought, I don't expect any logs to appear until query has completed on `Presto` because [1] your `talk_to_presto()` function logs only query result [2] [`PrestoHook`'s `get_records()`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/hooks/presto_hook.py#L80) function doesn't seem to generate any logs and just invokes [`DbApiHook`'s `get_records()`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/hooks/dbapi_hook.py#L98) function, which also doesn't generate any logs. So non-generation of logs is a direct consequence of non-completion of queries

Comment: @y2k-shubham From the PrestoDB query panel, I can see that no queries have reached there from the DAG. Also, remote-logging isn't enabled as well, I will try that too.